# find second max in a table using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a database with one table called "user" having two fields:

```
"id" (type: INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY) 
"name" (type: VARCHAR(32))
```

I want to Write a standard SQL query which retrieves the second highest value of "id" from the "user" table. The value returned should be represented using the column name "id".

I have tried this but it gives me all ids:

```
SELECT `user`.`id`
FROM `user`
ORDER BY `user`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

some example data in my table:

```
id      name
----------------
1       john
2       david
3       mike
```

I want to get '2' but now i'm getting :

```
id
----
1
2
3
```

I can do it with help of PHP but I want to know the way with mysql (SQL).
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM `user`
ORDER BY id DESC            -- start with highest
LIMIT 1                     -- show only 1 row
OFFSET 1 ;                  -- but skip the first (skip 1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1



select max(id) from user where id < (select max(id) from user);


select max(id) from user where id  not in (Select max(id) from user);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
FROM `user`
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Using `limit` you can set an offset and the number of records you like being returned.

Comment: `LIMIT 1,1` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout

```
Select max(id) from user
where id <> (select max(id) from user)
```

Answer (score -1):

This may work:

```
select max(id)-1 from user;
```